# Ubuntu unresponsive with high latency after clean-install of 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I just clean installed 18.04 onto a SSD. After this, my Ubuntu mouse always seems a bit behind and whenever I scroll, or open a new app, the entire monitor reloads from top to bottom. It takes a good second or so for this reload animation to finish. Literally the only things I have installed right now is git + VS Code + default apps, so it shouldn't be something I downloaded. I am running the default drivers, if that helps, and nomodeset is turned on in GRUB. How can I fix the weird scrolling action?

Edit: Using text-based editors only (like VIM, or terminal) doesn't exhibit any issues.

Edit 2: Getting rid of nomodeset fixes the problem

Comment: nomodeset is a clue to your problem... with your video subsystem. Why did you implement nomodeset, and have you installed appropriate drivers for your video card?

Comment: I'll try taking it off, but every guide I've looked at for graphics-related problems have suggested turning nomodeset on.

Comment: By golly you're a wiz harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

User had **nomodeset** enabled in GRUB, for an unknown reason, thereby disabling the video subsystem software.

Removing **nomodeset** fixed the problem.